# SFTP Chroot Error: Broken Pipe

Tags: 20.04, permissions, ssh, sftp

**Update: The code below has been updated to reflect the changes identified in the marked answer, and is therefore working as expected.**

I am trying to establish SFTP-only users on my server, that are jailed to their home directory. When attempting to connect to the server, I receive a broken pipe error:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xxxx.xxxxxxxx.com ([XX.XX.XX.XX]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to XX.XX.XX.XX port 22: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I have determined that this is related to my attempts to jail the user. My `sshd_config` includes:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftponly
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory /home/sftp
        PermitTunnel no
        AllowAgentForwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
```

`sftponly` is the name of the group I created for sftp users. The owner and group of `/home/sftp` is `root` with only write-permission for the owner (`0711`).

```
$  chown root:root /home/sftp
$  chmod 0711 /home/sftp
```

Here is how I'm creating users (in this example, `batman`) -- note that I'm doing this via a Perl script, hence my use of `chpasswd`:

```
$  adduser --quiet --disabled-password --shell /bin/false --no-create-home --gecos "User" batman
$  echo "batman:batman123" | chpasswd
$  usermod -a -G sftponly batman
$  install -d -m 0755 /home/sftp/batman -o batman -g sftponly
```

Note: I'm manually creating the users home directory rather than passing the `--system` arg for [adduser](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/adduser.8.html), as I end up getting an error when I later try and change the directory ownership:

> chown: invalid group: ‘batman:batman’

If I update my `sshd_config`, and change the chroot directory to:

```
ChrootDirectory /home/sftp
```

I can successfully access the server and no longer receive the broken pipe error. However, I land in `/home/sftp` upon login, where I see a list of all other user directories, rather than landing in `/home/sftp/batman` as I would expect to happen.

How can I improve/fix this, such that users:

- only have access to their own directory (`/home/sftp/batman`)
- upon login, will appear to be within `/` (which is actually `/home/sftp/batman`)
- cannot navigate to `/home/sftp` (so that they cannot see a list of other users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to accomplish this by applying these permissions:

```
$  chown batman:sftponly /home/sftp/batman
$  chmod 0755 /home/sftp/batman
$  chmod 0711 /home/sftp
```

Then changing the `ChrootDirectory` from `/home/sftp/%u` to `/home/sftp`,

And lastly moving the user into their home directory upon login:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u
```

Now, when `batman` logs in, they land in `/home/sftp/batman`, which appears as `/batman` to the user. More importantly, if they attempt to back out into `/home/sftp`, they receive an error (thereby preventing them from see other user directories):

> Directory /: permission denied - Failed to retrieve directory listing